# How to make Javascript syntax (condtional with if-else) more efficient to make it better and easier to understand (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can anyone give me idea how to make this syntax more efficient and easier to understand? I make it like this in Vue's methods section:

```
methods: {
    getColorBtn(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 1 && isRemind === 1) return 'v-btn--outlined theme--light primary--text'
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'primary plain--text'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) {
        return 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light success--text shadow-none'
      }
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 0) {
        return 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light primary--text shadow-none'
      }

      return 'primary'
    },
    textButton(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 1 && isRemind === 1) return 'Corrected'
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'Correction'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'Reminded'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 0) return 'Remind'

      return 'primary'
    },
    getIcon(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 1 && isRemind === 1) return 'd-none'
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'd-none'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return mdiBellCheckOutline
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 0) return mdiBellOutline

      return ''
    },
    getColorChip(status) {
      if (status === 1) return 'v-chip-light-bg success--text'

      return 'v-chip-light-bg error--text'
    },
}
the result

The data() (Btw, I just show it with 1 data as example here. Just to show the structure to y'all):

data() {
    return {
      isHide: true,
      icons: {
        mdiBellOutline,
        mdiBellCheckOutline,
      },
      students: [
        {
          no: '1',
          thumbnail,
          name: 'Ridho Mckinnon',
          status: 1,
          time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021',
          isCorrect: 1,
          isRemind: 1,
        },
    }
}
```

The result: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUexc.png)

The data() (Btw, I just show it with 1 data as example here. It's a dummy):

```
data() {
    return {
      isHide: true,
      icons: {
        mdiBellOutline,
        mdiBellCheckOutline,
      },
      students: [
        {
          no: '1',
          thumbnail,
          name: 'Ridho Mckinnon',
          status: 1,
          time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021',
          isCorrect: 1,
          isRemind: 1,
        },
    }
}
```

I really new in JS and Vue. I hope you all would to help me how to code better than those. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use nested arrays or objects.

```
const colorButtons = {
    field: 'status',
    1: {
        field: 'isCorrect',
        1: {
            field: 'isRemind',
            1: 'v-btn--outlined theme--light primary--text'
        },
        0: {
            field: 'isRemind',
            1: 'primary plain--text'
        }
    0: {
        field: 'isCorrect',
        0: {
            field: 'isRemind',
            1: 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light success--text shadow-none',
            0: 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light primary--text shadow-none'
        }
    }
}

getColorBtn(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
    return colorButtons.?[status].?[iscorrect].?[isRemind] || 'primary';
}
```

Repeat this similarly for the other functions.

Comment: This is "simpler" in that it uses less code space but I wouldn't consider it easy to understand

Comment: True, the meaning of all the objects and properties isn't obvious.

Comment: @Rylee I've added an extra property to annotate it.